# Audit List field level changes - SharePoint

Tags: list, versioning, auditing

Is it possible to audit changes on List fields in SharePoint 2013? What I'm looking for is to get some report when certain fields in a List is changed by users, not looking for values but just a report on which of the fields were changed?

Answer (score 2):

There are certain classes defined inside Microsoft.SharePoint namespace which you can use to customize your audit report.

1. SPAudit
2. SPAuditEntry
3. SPAuditEventType
4. SPAuditQuery

Please look into this URL.It actually tells you about auditing and different levels of auditing in Sharepoint.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/431342/Auditing-A-Built-in-Feature-of-SharePoint

**Without Server Coding**

We can use audit feature of Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 or SharePoint Online to track which users have taken what actions on the sites, content types, lists, libraries, list items, and library files within your site collections

[image]

**So in List,Libraries and Sites category you can check the event "Editing Content types and columns to get the columns that have been modified or edited by user"**

The audit log captures the following information for the events that are selected to be audited.

- Site from which an event originated
- Item ID, type, name, and location
- User ID associated with the event
- Event type, date, time, and source
- Action taken on the item

**To view Audit log reports**

[image]

Comment: I was hoping to do this without writing any server side code and just get details of fields names and not values. Not sure if I can do this using a SPD workflow.

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Comment: Hi Amit, appreciate your response. I'm aware of these audit reports which are OOB. What I'm looking for is to identify which fields have changed instead of a list of all activities on a list. The ideal report would display just field names (from my list) that have changed since the item was first created with the modified by value. I could work with the existing SP audit reports to get what I want but it involves quite a bit of work.

Comment: @Manu: interesting question, did you find a solution in the meantime?

Comment: nope, I have not found a solution.